# Can I use a pointer to a nested struct as a receiver parameter?

Tags: go, pointers, receiver

By using `x *A` as a receiver I could reference B as `x.B`
But I'd like to keep methods related to the B nested struct in their own *namespace* (if you will) by having a different receiver than the methods of the parent struct. *(And avoiding func name clashes)*

```golang
    type A struct {
        //...   
        B struct {
            // ...
        }
    }
    //...
    func (x *A.B) method() {
    
    }
```

Error: `A.B undefined (type A has no method B) compiler(MissingFieldOrMethod)`

Comment: `A.B` is not a *type;* `B` is a *field* within an object of type `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out I have to define B's type outside struct A and reference B directly in the receiver.
In my first example, B is an attribute of A of an unnamed type, and of course for a receiver parameter you have to reference a named type.
*(Or is there a way to reference an unnamed struct from its instance?)*

Corrected code:

```golang
    type A struct {
        //...
        b B
    }
    type B struct {
        }
    }
    //...
    func (x *B) method() {
    }
    //...
    a A = &A{}
    a.b.method()
```

Comment: There isn't a way at the moment. [Spec for Receiver](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receiver) says - `Its type must be a defined type T or a pointer to a defined type T`. [This is the spec for Type Definitions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions)